# Определения схожести одного значения к другому в PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, select, join, order-by

День добрый, хочу объединить кучу названий которые по смыслу одинаковые , но разные по написанию (разные в основном из за опечаток) бывает так что на одно название 20-30 похожих названий. Работаю с PostgreSQL 12.7.
Например одна компания OOO "VLADI" и исковерканные значения : "VLADI" , LTD "VLAD" , "vladi" , "vlad" и т.д. Думал использовать функцию similarity для определения схожести одного значения к другому и потом вместо них вести одно единственное верное (OOO "VLADI").
Вот что питался сделать я :

```
WITH DataB (CodCompanii,Compania) AS ( -- входная таблица с данными
     VALUES (1, 'ООО Vlad')
     ,(2, 'ООО "VLADD"')
     ,(3, 'ООО VlaD')
     ,(4, 'ОАО "VlAD"')
     ,(5, 'ЗАО VLaD')
     ,(6, 'ООО VLAD I')
     ,(7, 'ООО VLAd')
     ,(8, 'ZAO VLDI')
     ,(9, 'LTD VI')
     ,(10, 'Vlad')
     ),
compare (id, need) AS -- наша база для сопоставления
     (VALUES (100500, 'OOO "VLADI"')
)
SELECT c1.CodCompanii, c1.Compania, 'сравниваем с ' || c2.need, similarity(c1.Compania, c2.need) 
,dense_rank() OVER (PARTITION BY c2.need ORDER BY similarity(c1.Compania, c2.need) DESC) 
AS "Ранжирование результатов"
FROM DataB c1 CROSS JOIN compare c2
WHERE similarity(cCompania, c2.need) >0.3
ORDER BY similarity DESC;
```

Так я смог определить схожести одного з другим , но как потом перезаписать значение в столбец я не знаю. Или подскажите вариант по лучше. Помогите ибо очень много времени тратится на ручную редакцию.

Comment: А какое значение и в какой столбец писать ? Вообще можете после закрывающей скобки вашего with поставить запятую, обернуть ваш запрос внизу в еще один блок with, так что бы после него можно было написать просто `select * from X` и получить данные для перезаписи, т.е. id записи которую менять и значения которые писать. А после этого вместо этого select * пишите update с join

Comment: Очень интересно , но я кажется ничего не понял. Можете как-то показать , ибо я не понял "после закрывающей скобки вашего with поставить запятую, обернуть ваш запрос внизу в еще один блок with"

Comment: В CodCompanii вписывается код компании , но я уверен что намудрил с этим (думал этим облегчить поиск совпадений) ,а в Compania идет название копании.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/tfmf5HmL

Comment: Выводит ошибку в
UPDATE TABLE t
   SET t.x = u.x
  JOIN UPDATE u ON u.y = t.y

Comment: ну вы его под себя перепишите, я так и не понял что и в какой таблице надо заменять

Comment: я еще не до конца понимаю синтаксис и что значит UPDATE TABLE t SET t.x = u.x JOIN UPDATE u ON u.y = t.y. а именно t.x = u.x и u.y = t.y. заменить надо в таблице "DataB" столбец "Compania" все похожие значения на значения с временой таблици "compare" со столбца "need".

Comment: это стандартный синтаксис update. `update таблика-которую-меняем алиас SET имя-стобца-который меняем = значение(колонка из другой таблицы) ну и дальше обычный join

Comment: UPDATE TABLE "DataB" SET c1.Compania = c2.need JOIN UPDATE compare ON c2.id = c1.CodCompanii Вот подставил свои даниие но всеравно дает ошибку. ERROR: ОШИБКА: синтаксическая ошибка в или поблизости "JOIN" LINE 25:   JOIN UPDATE compare ON c2.id = c1.CodCompanii

Comment: а слово table зачем. это и есть имя таблицы. И что такое c1 и c2, я не вижу где бы они были объявлены. зачем слово update после join. он такой же как и в select'ах этот join. `UPDATE "DataB" as c1 SET Compania = c2.need JOIN  compare c2 ON c2.id = c1.CodCompanii` как то так

Comment: всеравно ругается на JOIN

Comment: А блин, вечно путаю диалекты. в postgresql: `UPDATE "DataB" as c1 SET Compania = c2.need FROM compare c2 WHERE c2.id = c1.CodCompanii`

Comment: Спасибо за помощь , но это всё равно не решила мою проблему. Я учел что я плохо расписал что мне надо поэтому создал похожий вопрос но с более понятной формулировкой.